# Find all the covering spaces of the Klein Bottle

Tags: algebraic-topology

I am studying for a qualifying exam and it asks for all the covering spaces of the Klein Bottle.  Does anyone have any suggestions?  I am not sure how to go about finding ALL of them.

Comment: You should use the one-one correspondence between covers and subgroups. So to classify all the covers you need to describe subgroups of $\pi_1(K)$.

Comment: @SashaPatotski: That is very hard, isn't it? Think about Euler characteristic.

Comment: yeah but how do I know the covering must be compact?  Is this an assumption that follows from something?

Comment: The universal cover is $\mathbb{R}^2$ --- certainly not compact!

Comment: so then how is euler characteristic useful?

Comment: I have that the torus and Klein bottle are coverings.  Not sure how to see that $\mathbb{R}^2$ is a covering.

Comment: @TedShifrin Maybe I am confusing something, but I don't think it's too hard. The fundamental group has presentation $\langle a,b\mid aba^{-1}=b^{-1}\rangle$. It has normal subgroup generated by $b$, which is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$. So if we take the quotient of $\pi_1$ by this subgroup, it will be isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$. So to classify all the subgroups of $\pi_1$, we have two cases: the subgroup maps to $0$ in the quotient or to some non-trivial subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}$. Both cases are not too difficult to describe. Am I missing something?

Comment: You're right. It's only useful for the compact ones. You certainly should know $\mathbb R^2$ is the universal covering. @SashaPatotski: Something seems fishy there! What is the abelianization of $\pi_1$? But can you figure out the finite covering spaces with this approach?